# How to add videos in a windows form applctn?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a form design of my Application:

[image: This is a form design of my Application]

In my application there is a button named movie. What i want to do is when clicked the button it open the movies folder in my computer and when clicked the video file the video plays. Anybody have any idea. Plz help

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698534/how-do-i-play-movies-in-a-c-sharp-winform-application

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Unfortunately, this is an _extremely_ broad question and you've provided no research or an example of a problem to solve; it is better suited for a google search first so that you can try to get started on your own.  If you're having trouble "getting started on your own" that's also better suited for another site until your have a concrete programming challenge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I play movies in a C# WinForm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698534/how-do-i-play-movies-in-a-c-sharp-winform-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you know basic WinForms development.

You first need to add `Windows Media Player` control to your Toolbox.

1. Right-click on Toolbox
2. Select 'Choose Items...'
3. Select 'COM Components' tab
4. Select 'Windows Media Player'
5. Click on 'OK' button.
6. The `Windows Media Player` control is now added to your `Components`
   tab of your Toolbox

[image]

Once you have `Windows Media Player` control in your Toolbox:

1. Add `Windows Media Player` to your form.
2. Set `URL` property of the control with movie file path you have
   selected.

`wmPlayer.URL = @"C:\Movies\somenicemovie.mp4"; // This value comes from movie selection dialog`

For reference and more customisation options, you can refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio

And

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/player-uimode

Hope this helps!